# How could installing Visual Studio 2017 break node.js or the typescript compiler?

Tags: node.js, angular, typescript, visual-studio-2017, tsc

I've installed the latest version of Visual Studio 2017; one of the install options I chose was to include the node.js support.

I'm not entirely sure what the installer has done, but I have been working on an angular 2 project for several months;  the last time I changed the code was over a month ago before installing VS2017.

The code for the app is not a problem (the app itself is currently working fine in its deployed environment on an IIS web server) - the problem appears to be with `tsc` the typescript compiler; nearly all of the errors are from typescript core libraries, seemingly not recognising built-in typescript types.

The project is based on the [angular2 quickstart seed](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/setup.html) from some time back in November 2016.

Today, when I run `npm start` I'm seeing the following typescript errors relating the core libraries:

```
C:\Source\website>npm start

> angular-quickstart@1.0.0 start C:\Source\website
> tsc && concurrently "tsc -w" "lite-server"

node_modules/@angular/core/src/facade/lang.d.ts(12,17): error TS2693: 'Map' only refers to a type, but is being used as a value here.
node_modules/@angular/core/src/facade/lang.d.ts(13,17): error TS2693: 'Set' only refers to a type, but is being used as a value here.
node_modules/@types/core-js/index.d.ts(47,36): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'Iterable'.
node_modules/@types/core-js/index.d.ts(350,48): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'PropertyKey'.
node_modules/@types/core-js/index.d.ts(351,52): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'PropertyKey'.

       .
       .
       .
   (... The list of errors carries on for many other .ts libraries)
```

I've attempted several solutions already:

This issue on github https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/21968 suggests two solutions:

Firstly, adding this into `tsconfig.json` didn't fix the problem:

```
  "compilerOptions": {
    ...
    "types" : [ "node", "jasmine", "core-js" ]
  }
```

Also running these two commands didn't fix the problem either:

```
npm i -D @types/core-js
npm i -D core-js
```

Lastly, trying to change the `target` in tsconfig.json to various different things including `es5`, `es6`, `es2015` do not fix the problem either.

Here's my original unmodified `tsconfig.json`:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es5",
    "module": "commonjs",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "removeComments": false,
    "noImplicitAny": true,
    "suppressImplicitAnyIndexErrors": true,
    "typeRoots": [
      "./node_modules/@types/"
    ]
  },
  "compileOnSave": true,
  "exclude": [
    "node_modules/*",
    "**/*-aot.ts"
  ]
}
```

And the `package.json`:

```
{
  "name": "angular-quickstart",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "QuickStart package.json from the documentation, supplemented with testing support",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "tsc && concurrently \"tsc -w\" \"lite-server\" ",
    "docker-build": "docker build -t ng2-quickstart .",
    "docker": "npm run docker-build && docker run -it --rm -p 3000:3000 -p 3001:3001 ng2-quickstart",
    "pree2e": "npm run webdriver:update",
    "e2e": "tsc && concurrently \"http-server -s\" \"protractor protractor.config.js\" --kill-others --success first",
    "lint": "tslint ./app/**/*.ts -t verbose",
    "lite": "lite-server",
    "test": "tsc && concurrently \"tsc -w\" \"karma start karma.conf.js\"",
    "test-once": "tsc && karma start karma.conf.js --single-run",
    "tsc": "tsc",
    "tsc:w": "tsc -w",
    "webdriver:update": "webdriver-manager update"
  },
  "keywords": [],
  "author": "",
  "licenses": [
    {
      "type": "MIT",
      "url": "https://github.com/angular/angular.io/blob/master/LICENSE"
    }
  ],
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/common": "~2.1.2",
    "@angular/compiler": "~2.1.2",
    "@angular/core": "~2.1.2",
    "@angular/forms": "~2.1.2",
    "@angular/http": "~2.1.2",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "~2.1.2",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "~2.1.2",
    "@angular/router": "~3.1.2",
    "@angular/upgrade": "~2.1.2",
    "angular-in-memory-web-api": "~0.1.13",
    "bootstrap": "^3.3.7",
    "core-js": "^2.4.1",
    "font-awesome": "^4.7.0",
    "primeng": "^1.1.0",
    "reflect-metadata": "^0.1.8",
    "rxjs": "5.0.0-beta.12",
    "systemjs": "0.19.40",
    "zone.js": "^0.6.26"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@types/core-js": "^0.9.41",
    "@types/jasmine": "^2.5.36",
    "@types/node": "^6.0.46",
    "@types/selenium-webdriver": "^2.53.33",
    "canonical-path": "0.0.2",
    "concurrently": "^3.1.0",
    "core-js": "^2.4.1",
    "http-server": "^0.9.0",
    "jasmine-core": "~2.4.1",
    "karma": "^1.3.0",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "^2.0.0",
    "karma-cli": "^1.0.1",
    "karma-htmlfile-reporter": "^0.3.4",
    "karma-jasmine": "^1.0.2",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^0.2.2",
    "lite-server": "^2.2.2",
    "lodash": "^4.16.4",
    "protractor": "4.0.9",
    "rimraf": "^2.5.4",
    "tslint": "^3.15.1",
    "typescript": "^2.1.4",
    "webdriver-manager": "10.2.5"
  },
  "repository": {}
}
```

I've tried reinstalling node.js - currently using version `6.10.2` although I've tried `7.0.0` with no success.

I'm running Typescript version 2.1.0

I'm running Windows 10.   The path for nodejs is in my System `%PATH%` environment variable:

```
c:\Program Files\nodejs\
```

Here's the full text for the system `%PATH%` entry:

```
C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:\Windows\System32\Wbem;C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\Program Files (x86)\NVIDIA Corporation\PhysX\Common;C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\Client SDK\ODBC\110\Tools\Binn\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\120\Tools\Binn\;C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\120\Tools\Binn\;C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\120\DTS\Binn\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\120\Tools\Binn\ManagementStudio\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\120\DTS\Binn\;C:\Program Files\TortoiseSVN\bin;C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\130\Tools\Binn\;C:\Program Files\Microsoft\Web Platform Installer\;C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\110\Tools\Binn\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\TypeScript\1.0\;C:\Program Files (x86)\GitExtensions\;%SystemRoot%\system32;%SystemRoot%;%SystemRoot%\System32\Wbem;%SYSTEMROOT%\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Emulator Manager\1.0\;%APPDATA%;C:\Program Files\Git\cmd;C:\Program Files\dotnet\;C:\Program Files\nodejs\
```

---

**Questions:**

1. Is it possible that a PATH variable has been broken and/or is pointing to the wrong install of node.js?
2. Is there anything else other than packages.config which determines the version of `tsc.exe` ?
3. Are there any other environment variables or configuration settings which Visual Studio 2017 could possibly have messed with to break this?
4. Has Visual Studio 2017 installed an older node.js (or maybe some newer unconfigured nodejs) somewhere else that I can't see in my list of installed programs?  would that cause a conflict?
5. Is something overriding the `tsc.exe` path?

---

**Update**

The following didn't work:

- Removed the typescript SDK path from the system `%PATH%`
- Un-installed node.js, and re-installed the latest version of node.js (Both the "recommended for most users" and the absolute latest)
- Reinstalled the latest typescript SDK
- Used npm to install the latest typescript
- Removed the `npm` folder from %APPDATA%
- Moved the `nodejs` path to the top of the list
- Rebooted the computer after all those changes..

---

***Another Update***

When I use a "clean" angular2 quickstart seed `npm-start` seems to work, but the command line that it uses for `tsc` has changed.

The command-line for the latest quickstart seed is `tsc -p src/ -w`

The command-line that I'm using is `tsc && concurrently "tsc -w" "lite-server"`

However, the commandline itself doesn't seem to matter.    In my current implementation, if I run `tsc` on its own without any parameters it seems to throw up all the same errors

I'm beginning to think there may be an issue with the way typescript works against one of the configuration files - perhaps system.js

---

**Final Update**

Removing Typescript the %PATH% seemed to change the version of `tsc` used on the command line but didn't solve the problem.    The %PATH% variable didn't seem to affect `npm start`

Somehow it looks as if npm is stuck using an old version of Typescript, and it seems to be something specific to the project, even though the project hasn't changed.

Perhaps this was "working by accident" before and Visual Studio 2017 has overwritten whatever caused it to work.

---

Comment: I have experienced this recently and it was the PATH variable that messed up. Also, just insure that you install typescript globally via NPM. In your path i could see a reference to TypeScript 1.0. Please try removing that!

Comment: @Digvijay very well spotted.   That helped, but something else still seems to be wrong.   I'm looking at other ways that the path to `tsc.exe` might be affected

Comment: Check the TypeScriptToolsVersion tag in the project file.

Comment: @Digvijay There is no project file - I'm not actually running this from within Visual Studio at all - it's just a folder, and I'm doing everything in VScode using NPM.      The problem seems to be the way that NPM is finding tsc

Comment: Try a reboot - that's what fixed it for me after cleaning up the path variable.

Comment: @Digvijay Thanks, I've tried that but still seeing the same error.    The path variable certainly seems to be updated.

Answer (score 0):

***I cannot see any easy way to fix this***.  So for now I'm going to work-around it by migrating all of my code to the latest angular 2 seed.

The latest angular 2 seed isn't backward compatible to the version I had in November, but it seems that the changes aren't too unmanagable:

**Changes required to the angular 2 project source code:**

*(Migrating from Nov 2016 quickstart to March 2017 quickstart)*

1. Get the latest seed from https://github.com/angular/quickstart
2. Move all `app` files (along with `styles.css` and `index.html`) into the seed's new folder structure with the `src` directory
3. in `index.html` Change `System.import('app')` to `System.import('main.js')`
4. Remove `Reflect.js` from `index.html`
5. Remove `module: module.id` from `@Component()` decorators - this affects a lot of files, so a mass search+replace is needed.
6. change `main.js` to point to `./app/app.module` instead of `./app.module`

Now the project builds and functions as before, but the underlying problem isn't fixed.   While I have worked around my specific problem, I'm going to leave this question here un-answered because there is still a problem somewhere, and the information might be useful if anybody can figure out what the actual root cause is.